# Send and Read Binary Data over WebSocket (Standanlone VM)

Tags: dart

I try to send and read Binary Data over Websocket with Dart. But I couldn’t find a Solution.

Another Question is how can I serialize any data Object/JSON/Text and so forth into a Binary Stream and Back.

Because I hope that will run:

```
ws.add(binaryStream);
```

Many Thanks  in Advance.

Comment: Try [Websocket.send(blob)](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-dom-html.WebSocket@id_send) instead of add(). I guess for streams of binary data, you can send them one chunk at a time, but I haven't tried this. Also note, server and client site Websocket classes are bit different.

Comment: Yes you right. But i do my tests on Dart(Server) (import 'dart:io')

Comment: Ah right. I assumed you were writing client side code. Consider adding some more detail to the question.